# SQL Command to execute multiple times?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have situations that I need to write multiple rows of the same value to setup some tables. Say I have to add 120 rows with two columns populated. I am looking for a shortcut, instead of having the Insert line repeated n times. How to do this?

Comment: Can you simply put your insert statement into some while loop?

Comment: I could but I would be doing it in VB and figured that sending back/forth to server would be best avoided. Is there away to do a loop in a sp in SQL 2005?

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server Management Studio, you can use the "GO" keyword with a parameter:

```
INSERT INTO YourTable(col1, col2, ...., colN)
VALUES(1, 'test', ....., 25)
GO 120
```

But that works only in Mgmt Studio (it's not a proper T-SQL command - it's a Mgmt Studio command word).

Marc

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
Insert Table( colsnames )
Select Top 120 @value1, @Value2, etc.
From AnyTableWithMoreThan120Rows
```

Just make sure the types of the values in the @Value list matches the colNames List

Comment: Most system tables will have enough rows for this.

Comment: but I don't have these values in a table. Creating a table for them would defeat the purpose

Comment: The insert is not getting the data from the table, it is just using the table to get a defined number of rows.  The select clause should only contain references to parameter values passed in. Like if you executed [Select 'MyName' from tablewith1000Rows]  you would get 1000 rows with 'MyName' in them, and no data from the table

Answer (score 1):

what about

```
insert into  tbl1
 (col1,col2)
(select top 120 @value1,@value2 from tbl2)
```

if in **sql server 2008** . new in sql server 2008 to insert into a table multiple rows in a single query .

```
insert into  tbl1
 (col1,col2)
values
(@value1,@value2),(@value1,@value2),.....(@value1,@value2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the values in an unused table for safe keeping. From there you can insert from this table to the tables you need to setup.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an Excel Spreadsheet with your data.
2. Import the speadsheet into Sql Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can even try with something like this(just an example)

```
declare @tbl table(col1 varchar(20),col2 varchar(20))
; with generateRows_cte as
(
    select 
        1 as MyRows

       union all
        select 
            MyRows+1

        from    generateRows_cte   
        where   MyRows < 120
)
insert into @tbl(col1,col2)
select 
'col1' + CAST(MyRows as varchar),'col2' + CAST(MyRows as varchar)
from generateRows_cte OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
select * from @tbl
```

Note:- Why not you are trying with Bulk insert into SqlServer from a dataset ? I didnot notice first that u have a front end too(VB)!

Comment: Like Charles' solution but maybe better since creates the table on the fly. I love it. thanks.

Comment: even you can take the help of some system tables like SYS.COLUMNS,master..spt_values etc. for accomplishing ur task